# How to get entity by child id while child is already deleted?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I have this entity:

```
class Room(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    fb_user = db.ReferenceProperty(FbUser)
```

I have `fb_user_id = 131` but I have deleted that `fb_user` already.
How to get `room` of that `fb_user` by that `fb_user_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution for my own question:

```
k = db.Key.from_path(FbUser.kind(), 131) 
room = Room.all().filter('fb_user =', k).get()
db.delete(room)
```